# Replaced timeout event fires twice or more (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout

I have a section of content that allows a user to edit it upon double-clicking on it. If the user changes the content and then stops for 2 seconds, the updated content is sent to the server to be saved.

To do so, I have bound an `input` event listener to that section that starts a 2 seconds countdown, and if there is already a countdown, the former will be cancelled and a new one will start instead. At the end of the countdown an http POST request is sent to the server with the new data.

The problem is that sometimes at the end of the countdown I see 2 or more requests sent, as if a countdown was not cancelled before a new one was inserted, and I can't figure out why.

The code in question is as follows:

```
//this function is bound to a double-click event on an element
function makeEditable(elem, attr) {

    //holder for the timeout promise
    var toSaveTimeout = undefined;

    elem.attr("contentEditable", "true");
    elem.on("input", function () {

        //if a countdown is already in place, cancel it
        if(toSaveTimeout) {
            //I am worried that sometimes this line is skipped from some reason
            $timeout.cancel(toSaveTimeout);
        }
        toSaveTimeout = $timeout(function () {
            //The following console line will sometimes appear twice in a row, only miliseconds apart
            console.log("Sending a save. Time: " + Date.now());
            $http({
                url: "/",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    action: "edit_content",
                    section: attr.afeContentBox,
                    content: elem.html()
                }
            }).then(function (res) {
                $rootScope.data = "Saved";
            }, function (res) {
                $rootScope.data = "Error while saving";
            });
        }, 2000);
    });

    //The following functions will stop the above behaviour if the user clicks anywhere else on the page
    angular.element(document).on("click", function () {
        unmakeEditable(elem);
        angular.element(document).off("click");
        elem.off("click");
    });
    elem.on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a `console.log` to the `if(toSaveTimeout) {` block to see if it is getting in it?

Comment: Everytime you call the `makeEditable` function your toSaveTimeout is undefined because it is bound to this function scope. Your test `if(toSaveTimeout)` will always fail.

Comment: ensure you dont call `makeEditable` twice

Comment: @Franck: I think the user would only double-click ones. So user double clicks, then starts typing in the input. And after every input to the input it should wait 2 seconds and send a request to the server. And it should cancel the 2 second timer if the user inputs again before the 2 seconds. That is what it sounds like to me.

Comment: A jsFiddle might help here...

Comment: Also, try adding a `console.log` to the start of `makeEditable` to see if it, for some reason, is getting called twice, meaning it is adding two `input` events to `elem`.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan is correct. But Franck and Vladimir put up a good point, it could be that the makeEditable function is called twice. I will check for that.

Comment: Okay, yes :-(. that was the problem. double-clicking and double-clicking again when the element is already in an editable state appears to be the only cause of the issue. Thank you

Comment: Also, shouldn't it send update to the server every 2 seconds? `setTimeout` will only call once. Don't you want `setInterval`?

Comment: Oh no, I don't want to send an update if nothing is changed. If I'll do it with an interval user input will no longer be a factor. I'm assuming of course that user input is the only way to change the content, and given that I'm the one who built the page this is a safe assumption :-)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out (with help from the commentators above) that the function `makeEditable` was called more than once.

Adding the following two lines of code at the beginning of the function fixed the issue:

```
//if element is already editable - ignore
if(elem.attr("contentEditable") === "true")
    return;
```

Comment: Do you know why/how `makeEditable` was being called twice? Anyway to stop/fix that so it is never called twice instead of checking if it was already called? I mean, both work but I feel like stopping it at its source is better.

Comment: (You might also want to mark your answer as the answer.)

Comment: There are many reasons why that might happen, it could be even a hardware issue like a crazy mouse sending multiple mouse clicks. But one of the reasons is also a user double-clicks again just cause (maybe s/he didn't understand the concept or thought this was the way to save) and the only way to prevent the issue from surfacing at that scenario is the lines of code above. (and yes I will, but rules state 24 hours before accepting your own answer)